# Rails form_helper can not burn "update" action after ajax requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-helpers

I'm try to implement related select-option menus with Ajax like country-city relation.

When I try to rendering form from `_form.html.erb` in new and edit views. I could not edit articles, when I submited form in `edit.html.erb`, `article#create` action burns instead of `article#update`.

Obviously Ajax is causing this problem. But I can't figure out how can I solve this problem.

I try to put form in `edit.html.erb` instead of render it and change form helper url adress like `url: { action: "update" }` but then I came across this error `No route matches [POST] "/foo/123"`.

`categories/edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for :category, url: { action: "update" } do |f| %>
Category 1: <%= f.collection_select(:parent_id, @categories, :id, :name,  {:include_blank => 'No Parent'}, { :id => 'C1', name: 'parent[id1]' } ) %>

Category 2: <%= f.collection_select(:parent_id, @categories, :id, :name,  {:include_blank => 'No Parent'}, { :id => 'C2', name: 'parent[id2]' } ) %>


<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#C1').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= children_category_path %>",
        data: {
                id : $('#C1 option:selected').val(),
                which : "C1",
                form : "categories"
                },
        dataType: "script"
        });
    });
    $('#C2').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= children_category_path %>",
        data: {
                id : $('#C2 option:selected').val(),
                which : "C2",
                form : "categories"
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
</script>
```

`get.js.coffee`

```
<% if @class == "C1" %>
$("#C2")
        .empty()
        <% if @form == "categories" %>
                .append("<option value> </option>")
        <% end %>
        .append("<%= escape_javascript(options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name)) %>");

<% end %>
<% if @class == "C2" %>
$("#C3")
        .empty()
        <% if @form == "categories" %>
                .append("<option value> </option>")
        <% end %>
        .append("<%= escape_javascript(options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name)) %>");
<% end %>
```

`categories_controller.rb`

```
def edit

        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
        @categories = Category.roots
end

def update
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])

        if @category.update(create_params)
                redirect_to categories_path
        else
                render 'edit'
        end
end
```

`children_controller.rb`

```
 def get
         @class = params[:which]
         @form = params[:form]
         @categories = Category.find(params[:id]).children
         respond_to do |format|
                 format.js
         end
 end
```

Comment: When I look another example for edit action. When Update action burn there are two parameters method => "_patch" and action => "update". May I have to add these parameters when try to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= form_for :category, url: { action: "update" } do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
```

so that rails will be able to know you are editing that object and will address the request properly to `update` action.